# Database connections break when simultaneous connections (Crystal-lang)

Tags: mysql, crystal-lang

I set up a class with this class property:

```
@@db : DB::Database = DB.open "mysql://root:root@localhost/db_name"
```

Then, in any class method I can use `@@db`:

```
@@db.query("select * from thing") do |rs|
    rs.each do
        # make object
    end
end
```

I was hoping this way I could `DB.open` only when the app starts, and not again for each request. This works great... until I run `wrk -c10` and test multiple connections at the same time. Here is some error feedback:

> Unhandled exception on HTTP::Handler Closed stream (IO::Error)
>   0x10e69a440: *raise:NoReturn at ?? 0x10e6a8d57:
>   *IO::FileDescriptor+@IO::Buffered#read:Int32 at ?? 0x10e7030db: *MySql::ReadPacket#read:Int32 at ??
>   0x10e74d89b: *DB::ResultSet+@DB::Disposable#close:(Bool | Nil) at ??
>   0x10e745ba2: *DefaultController::database:Nil
>   at ?? 0x10e7500c4:
>   *HTTP::Server::RequestProcessor#process<(OpenSSL::SSL::Socket::Server | TCPSocket+), (OpenSSL::SSL::Socket::Server | TCPSocket+),
>   IO::FileDescriptor>:Nil at ?? 0x10e6995fd:
>   *Fiber#run:(IO::FileDescriptor | Nil) at ??

I "fixed" the problem by doing this on each request:

```
DB.open("mysql://root:root@localhost/db_name") do |db|
    db.query("select * from thing") do |rs|
        rs.each do
            # make object
        end
    end
end
```

This works, but with awful performance. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like this was a bug and fixed in crystal-mysql's master branch. Please use `branch: master` under your `crystal-mysql` dependency in your `shard.yml` and then run `shards update` to fix this issue.